# kafka-server-start.bat results with ClearQuest\cqjni.jar was unexpected at this time

Tags: apache-kafka, clearquest

Kafka_2.12-1.0.0

CMD as Administrator:

> C:\kafka_2.12-1.0.0\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.12-1.0.0\config\server.properties

results with:

> \IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar was unexpected at this time.

Nothing more in cmd output.

System variables:
CLASSPATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the CLASSPATH variable set on the shell. 
I tried to unset CLASSPATH and worked for me.

Command 
unset CLASSPATH

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to start Kafka due to weird issue.
"\Documentum\DocLink\aspectjrt.jar was unexpected at this time."

Root cause of this issue classpath defined in System variable having entry for \Documentum\DocLink\aspectjrt.jar, CEP.jar, dice.jar.

Solution: I have removed entries from classpath for all jars lying under directory \Documentum\DocLink\

--> Advance Setting --> Environment Variable --> Classpath

Now Kafka server running perfectly in my system.